# Linear dependence of ODE solutions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Let be $y'(x)=A(x)y(x)$ an ODE and $y_1(x),y_2(x)\cdots,y_n(x)$ some solutions. Let be $Y(x)$ the Wronskian of the those solutions.

We have proven the statement that if we find an $x_0$ such that rank$(Y(x_0))=n$, then all $y_1(x),y_2(x)\cdots,y_n(x)$ are linearly independent.

Our professor added that this means that we only have to check one value, i.e. plug $x_0$ into the Wronskian $Y(x)$, in order to determine if $y_1(x),y_2(x)\cdots,y_n(x)$ are linearly independent or not.

However, I don't see why this statement allows us to conclude that rank$(Y(x_0))<n$ means linear dependence of $y_1(x),y_2(x)\cdots,y_n(x)$?

Comment: IIRC a uniqueness argument applied to the ODE satisfied by the Wronskian implies that the Wronskian is either identically zero or nowhere zero. I might be mistaken however.

Comment: @Ian, Ah ok I think you are referring to an argument like: $Y(1):=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&2\end{pmatrix}\implies 2y_1(1)=y_2(1) \implies (2y_1(x))'=A(x)2y_1(x)$. So $2y_1(x)$ is a solution of the ODE. $2y_1(x)$ also satisfies the initial condition $2y_1(1)={2\choose 2}$. As we know that each initial condition produces a unique solution function it must be $2y_1(x)=y_2(x)$. Hence, $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Just assume that $\mathrm{rank}(Y(x_0)) < n$. This means that $Y(x_0)$ is a family of linearly dependent vectors. This implies that there exists a vector $(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n) \neq 0$ such that
$$
\sum_{j = 1}^n \lambda_j y_j(x_0) = 0.
$$
Note that solutions are unique for these kinds of linear ODEs and that
$$
g(x) := \sum_{j = 1}^n \lambda_j y_j(x)
$$
is also a solution. It fulfils the initial condition $g(x_0) = 0$ due to assumption. Because of uniqueness and since $0$ is also a solution, we must have
$$
0 = g(x) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \lambda_j y_j(x)
$$
for all $x$ and thus linear dependence.